Matrix with \guilsinglright, \guilsinglleft and \textlquill, \textrquill
I want to make matrices with \guilsinglright, \guilsinglleft and \textlquill, \textrquill. I thought it would work with \left and \right, but it doesn't:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\left\textlquill 
\begin{matrix}
    A \\B 
\end{matrix}
\right\textrquill 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\left\guilsinglleft
\begin{matrix}
A \\ B
\end{matrix}
\right\guilsinglright
\end{align}
\end{document}

The code produces an error: error: Missing delimiter (. inserted). \end{align} and the output is:

How to fix this error and how to make these matrices?

they are text punctuation not math, use \langle and \rangle (or equivalently < and >) for stretchy <> brackets.

Off-topic: You shouldn't use an align environment for a single-row displayed equation. Use an equation environment instead if you want to generate a numbered displayed equation.

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted in a comment, don't use text-mode-only commands in math mode. The results of using text-mode commands in this fashion are both highly unpredictable and likely quite undesirable -- as you've (re)discovered on your own.
I would also recommend using \langle and \rangle to generate angle backets.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
\biggl\langle 
  \begin{matrix} A \\ B \end{matrix}
\biggr\rangle 
\]
\end{document}


Thanks, I didn't know that  \guilsinglright, \guilsinglleft and \textlquill, \textrquill are text-only commands.

@Alezigl - You're welcome. As a rule, LaTeX commands that start with \text... should be used in text mode. :-) Naturally, if you know exactly what you're doing, you may be able to get away with breaking a LaTeX rule or two at a time... That said, though, I can see no reason for not using \langle and \rangle in math mode.

Thanks very much!
